# LEDs on Arduino WiFi Shield

Tags: led, wifi, shields, hardware

I would like to know the purpose of the LEDs on top of the Arduino WiFi Shield: L9/Link/Error/Data (left in the picture). What do they indicate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [web page on the Arduino site](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-wifi-shield) for the board tells you in plain words what they mean:

> On board indicators The shield contains a number of informational LEDs:
>
> - L9 (yellow) : this is tied to digital pin 9
> - LINK (green) : indicates a connection to a network
> - ERROR (red) : indicates when there is a communication error
> - DATA (blue) : indicates data being transmitted/received